# SuppressWarnings vs noinspection

Tags: intellij-idea

When when I choose to suppress for a statement, why does it sometimes insert a `@SuppressWarnings` and sometimes a `//noinspection`?

I'm talking about different statements, I assume that on the same statement it will always use the same variant. I specifically choose to suppress a statement (not method, class or anything else)

what's the difference?

Comment: Could you please give an example for two situations happened to you. ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@SuppressWarnings` is an annotation, and can only decorate classes, interfaces, and methods. IntelliJ uses `//noinspection` to mark warnings that cannot be suppressed by an annotation because they are not classes, interfaces, or methods.